# NativeScript - Dynamically changing background image of a page

Tags: background-image, nativescript

Is there a way to change the background image of a page in NativeScript dynamically? For example I want to have a set of images which should be displayed as the background image but only one image at a time and depending on the location or some other parameter.
I know in native android one can use layout.invalidate() to redraw the layout, but is there a similar feature available on NativeScript?

Comment: Sure - just change the background-image of the view. e.g. view.style.backgroundImage = "url('new-image.jpg')". The exact syntax depends wx the file is in a resource folder, in your app storage folder or the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) that worked for me.